On dual notions of morphisms of algebraic structures obtained by replacing equaliser with coequalisers
This question is based on this discussion from the Category Theory Zulip. See also the earlier question Natural cotransformations and "dual" co/limits.

Let $G$ and $H$ be groups. We define the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(G,H)$ of morphisms of groups from $G$ to $H$ by

We could dualise this definition to obtain the set $\mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(G,H)$ defined by

where $\mathord{\sim}$ is the equivalence relation on $\mathsf{Sets}(G,H)$ generated by declaring $f(ab)\sim f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$.
More explicitly, $\mathord{\sim}$ is the equivalence relation generated by the relation $\mathord{\sim}'$ declaring $f\sim' g$ if there exist $x\in G$ and a morphism $\phi\colon G\to H$ satisfying the following conditions:

For each $a\in G$, we have $f(a)=\phi(xa)$.
For each $a\in G$, we have $g(a)=\phi(x)\phi(a)$.

We might then call an element of $\mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(G,H)$ a "cohomomorphism of groups from $G$ to $H$".
The discussion on Zulip suggests there might or might not be a map
$$\circ\colon\mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(B,C)\times\mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(A,B) \to \mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(A,C)$$
as well as maps
\begin{align*}
\frown &\colon\mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(B,C)\times\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(A,B) \to \mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(A,C),\\
\frown &\colon\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(B,C)\times\mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(A,B) \to \mathrm{CoHom}_{\mathsf{Grp}}(A,C),
\end{align*}
but I haven't checked this yet.
Of course, the above discussion isn't exclusive to groups, there being analogous constructions for other algebraic structures. For instance a "comorphism" of $G$-sets from $(X,\triangleleft_{X})$ to $(Y,\triangleleft_{Y})$ would be an element of the quotient of $\mathsf{Sets}(X,Y)$ by the equivalence relation generated by declaring $f(a\mathbin{\triangleleft_{X}}x)\sim a\mathbin{\triangleleft_{Y}}f(x)$.
Question. Have these notions of morphisms of algebraic structures dual to the usual ones been studied before? Do they have any interesting applications?

Some worked examples would be useful to understand what's going on.  There could be significant differences between Abelian and non-Abelian groups, for example.
